# linking a static parameter to a textbox content value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, static

In my WPF application interface  have a textbox `labanglestart`

```
 private void labanglestart_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     double a;
     double.TryParse(labanglestart.Text.ToString(), 
                     NumberStyles.Number,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                     out a);

     if (a != null )
     {
         Global2.Pat_anglestart = a;
     }
     else
     {
         labanglestart.Text = Global2.Pat_anglestart.ToString();
     }
 }
```

And a static class `Global2` with its static property `Pat_anglestart`.

I'd like to do this:

- When i change the content of the textbox and i focus out it,

  - if the text inserted is castable to a double, then the static parameter take it as value
  - otherwise the content of the textbox will be the value of the parameter (after cast it to string).

The method above didn't work i.e. there was no change.

1. What is the reason?
2. How can i fix my snippet?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: no exception, but it seems that an infinite thread  is raised when i focus in the textbox and i try to modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handle textBox [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event,instead of `TextChanged`

```
private void labanglestart_LostFocus(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         double a;
         double.TryParse(labanglestart.Text.ToString(), NumberStyles.Number,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out a);
         if (a != null )
         {
             Global2.Pat_anglestart = a;
         }
         else
         {
             labanglestart.Text = Global2.Pat_anglestart.ToString();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

first, a will never be null

you have to check against the return of the tryparse statement.

```
private void labanglestart_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
 double a;


 if (double.TryParse(labanglestart.Text.ToString(), 
                 NumberStyles.Number,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                 out a))
 {
     Global2.Pat_anglestart = a;
 }
 else
 {
     labanglestart.Text = Global2.Pat_anglestart.ToString();
 }
 }
```

then if you need to do this against the lostFocus event, use that.